# React function is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Whenever I press a key and the handleKeyboardInteraction function below runs, I experience a

`TypeError: this.handleKeyboardPress is not a function`

What is the source of this? I'm not sure if using handleKeyPress as both a prop for a more deeply nested Component and as a regular function within my class is the issue. I tried introducing a brand new function that did the same functionality as handleKeyPress, but the error remained.

```
import React from "react";
import { DrumKit } from "./DrumKit.js";
import { Display } from "./Display.js";
import { Container, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import { convertCodeToKey, validKeyCodes } from "./CodeToKeyConverter.js";

export class DrumMachine extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      lastKeyPressed: ""
    };
    this.handleKeyPress = this.handleKeyPress.bind(this);
    this.handleKeyboardInteraction = this.handleKeyboardInteraction.bind(this);
  }

  handleKeyPress(keyPressed) {
    this.setState({
      lastKeyPressed: keyPressed
    });
  }

  handleKeyboardInteraction(event) {
    const keyCode = event.keyCode;
    if (validKeyCodes.includes(keyCode)) {
      let keyCurrent = convertCodeToKey(keyCode);
      this.handleKeyPress(keyCurrent);
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", this.handleKeyboardInteraction);
  }

  render() {
    const lastKeyPressed = this.state.lastKeyPressed;
    return (
      <Container>
        <Row xs={2} sm={2} md={2} lg={2}>
          <Col xs={10} sm={10} md={10} lg={10}>
            <DrumKit
              lastKeyPressed={lastKeyPressed}
              onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress}
            />
          </Col>
          <Col xs={2} sm={2} md={2} lg={2}>
            <Display lastKeyPressed={lastKeyPressed} />
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you have `handleKeyPress`  and `handleKeyboardInteraction`, but no `handleKeyboardPress`

Comment: The code you show does not contains any call to a function called `handleKeyboardPress`, can you share the full (expanded) error stack trace?

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I honestly don't know what to say. The problem resolved itself through no input of my own. I suspect that the environment I was using (codesandbox) was not running my most recently saved files.